# Symfony2: Twig: Default template file in custom location

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I try to load a simple `base.html.twig` template file that was moved from symfony's default location `app/Resources/views/` to the custom location `theme/`.

The template file contains:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
     ...
     </head>
     <body>
      {% block body %}{% endblock %}
     </body>
    </html>
```

Extending the above template file by the controller `Acme\Core\CoreBundle\Controller` by using the controller-specific template

```
    {% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
    {% block body %}
      Hello world!
    {% endblock %}
```

leads to an error saying `Unable to find template "::base.html.twig" in "AcmeCoreCoreBundle:Default:index.html.twig".`.

How is it possible to tell symfony where to find the template files in global space?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be done with the `\Twig_Loader_Filesystem::addPath($path, $namespace = '__main__')` ( see [Source](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php) ) but not sure where you would call it from. Also had a look at the TwigBundle configuration, but doesn't look like there's an option for it there. If someone where to expand further on this, it might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to Adam's hint I am able to answer the question on my own. So I want to provide my answer if anybody is interested in.

The `AcmeDemoBundle` provides a twig extension (class `Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\Extension\DemoExtension`) that you simply can use. Change the constructor to

```
    public function __construct(FilesystemLoader $loader)
    {
     $this->loader = $loader;
     $this->loader->addPath('path/to/your/directory');
    }
```

Now tell symfony to register the twig extension. Edit your `config.yml` file (e.g. `app/config/config.yml`) and append

```
    services:
     demo.twig.extension
      class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\Extension\DemoExtension
      tags:
       - { name: twig.extension }
      arguments:
       - @Twig.loader
```

Last but not least change your extending twig file and remove the `::` from your default template's namespace:
`{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}`.

Comment: Glad my hint pointed you in the right direction, and thanks for sharing. This solution is more elegant than the one I initially was thinking about providing.

Answer (score 12):

There's a native feature to do exactly what you want in a nice way. Escentially you can add a twig namespace to the twig configuration in app/config.yml like this:

```
twig:
    # ...
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/acme/foo-bar/templates": foo_bar
```

This creates an alias to the folder `vendor/acme/foo-bar/templates` and then you can use it to render your templates either from the controllers:

```
return $this->render(
    '@foo_bar/template.html.twig',
    $data
);
```

or from other twig templates

```
{% include '@foo_bar/template.html.twig' %}
```

Source: official cookbook http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html

Answer (score 5):

I managed to find another solution to this which is much quicker to implement.  I did try the accepted answer on this question first but was still having so path issues.

Just before my render call the template I added the path to the twig.loader container like this:

```
$this->container->get('twig.loader')->addPath('../../../../theme/', $namespace = '__main__');
```

Now twig templates will be rendered from a directory called 'theme' in the root folder. I found this solution from Fabien Pontencier himself (the creator of Symfony and Twig) on a reply to a twig bug here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1912

Comment: looking for exact this one!

Answer (score 2):

From an action you can get the 'twig.loader'-service from the (service)-container:

```
$this->get('twig.loader')->addPath('path/to/your/directory');
```

And then you can use this path in your template.

@besta did it with a twig extension, injecting the twig loader into the constructor. But in twig extension you can use the environment:

```
class YourTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
...
   public function initRuntime(\Twig_Environment $environment) {
      $this->environment = $environment;
      $this->environment->getLoader()->addPath(__DIR__ . '/Resources/views');
   }
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this done globally, this sort of stuff is meant to be done in a [compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#creating-a-compiler-pass).

It would be much cleaner and efficient like this:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class CustomCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = $container->getDefinition('twig.loader');
        $loader->addMethodCall('addPath', array('/path/to/views'));
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it comes back with `'You have requested a non-existent service "twig.loader"`. You need to use 'twig.loader.filesystem'