# Symfony render template from custom location

Tags: symfony, twig, absolute-path

I am trying to render template not using the Symfony2 required format 'Bundle:Controller:file_name', but want to render the template from some custom location.

The code in controller throws an exception

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class
>   __TwigTemplate_509979806d1e38b0f3f78d743b547a88 could not be converted to string in
>   Symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Debug/TimedTwigEngine.php
>   line 50

My code:

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates/');
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => __DIR__.'/../../../../app/cache/custom',
));
$tmpl = $twig->loadTemplate('index.twig.html');
return $this->render($tmpl);
```

Is it even possible to do such things in Symfony, or we have to use only logical names format?

Comment: look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952309/symfony2-twig-default-template-file-in-custom-location

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Solution**

You could do the following, replacing your last line `return $this->render($tmpl);`:

```
$response = new Response();
$response->setContent($tmpl);
return $response;
```

Don't forget to put a `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;` at the top of your controller though!

**Theory**

Alright, let's begin from where you are now. You are inside your controller, calling the `render` method. This method is defined as follows:

```
/**
 * Renders a view.
 *
 * @param string   $view       The view name
 * @param array    $parameters An array of parameters to pass to the view
 * @param Response $response   A response instance
 *
 * @return Response A Response instance
 */
public function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
{
    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse($view, $parameters, $response);
}
```

The docblock tells you that it expects a string which is the view name, not an actual template. As you can see, it uses the `templating` service and simply passed the parameters and return value back and forth.

Running `php app/console container:debug` shows you a list of all registered services. You can see that `templating` is actual an instance of `Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigEngine`. The method `renderResponse` has the following implementation:

```
/**
 * Renders a view and returns a Response.
 *
 * @param string   $view       The view name
 * @param array    $parameters An array of parameters to pass to the view
 * @param Response $response   A Response instance
 *
 * @return Response A Response instance
 */
public function renderResponse($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
{
    if (null === $response) {
        $response = new Response();
    }

    $response->setContent($this->render($view, $parameters));

    return $response;
}
```

You now know that when you call the `render` method, a Response object is passed back which is essentially a plain `Response` object on which setContent was executed, using a string representing the template.

I hope you don't mind I described it a bit more detailed. I did this to show you how to find a solution like this yourself.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the main thing i got from it was a php app/console container:debug. Previously i have tried to get the loader and twig environment, but without any success, thats why i have tried to create a new instance of environment and loader.

Comment: working for me : return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse